# Return list of spatial tables with at least one feature intersecting a given geometry?

Tags: postgis

I am trying to return a list of all spatial tables in my database that have at least one feature's geometry intersecting another specific geometry.

I am trying to wrap my head around what would be the most efficient way of doing this with a query. I assume that once a single feature has been found to intersect the specified geometry that I could terminate the query for that given table and the continue on to the next table.

What would be my best option to carry out such a task?

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by using a dynamic query and creating a cursor which loops through a selection of table names. You can derive which tables are spatial using the method proposed in the answer to [Selecting only Spatial tables from PostgreSQL database?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31061)

You can then define a PLPGSQL function ([see example](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20050930083434.GA86067%40winnie.fuhr.org)) that takes the table name as a string parameter and builds the spatial query (as a string stored in a varchar variable) with the table name injected into it. The EXECUTE command is then used to execute the dynamic query.

Inside the cursor you can call the function and pass in your cursors current value.

The SQL statement in the function should check to see there if the geometry column of the table which was passed contains any records which intersect the predefined geometry.

If the spatial query determines that the predefined geometry intersects any of the injected table's geometry column records, then do something with that information (return a value, insert record into a table, etc) and move on to the next record in the cursor.

What the end of the function does after it finds an intersect depends on what you actually want to do when you find an intersecting geometry.

Comment: This approach seems promising. The answer would be improved immeasurably with a dummied up SQL statement and actual PL/pgSQL function.